# GitHub Action unable to execute build executable

Tags: go, github, github-actions

Try to use GitHub Actions but getting error when trying to run executable build. I can find executable when doing `ls` and also changing mod of file executable but didn't got anything. Attached log/output of GitHub action.

Here is my github action workflow file

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

name: Build For platforms

jobs:
  build:
    # We want to define a strategy for our job
    strategy:
      # this will contain a matrix of all of the combinations
      # we wish to test again:
      matrix:
        go-version: [1.14.x]
        platform: [ubuntu-latest]
    
    # Defines the platform for each test run
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.platform }}
    
    # the steps that will be run through for each version and platform
    # combination
    steps:
    # sets up go based on the version
    - name: Install Go
      uses: actions/setup-go@v2
      with:
        go-version: ${{ matrix.go-version }}

    # checks out our code locally so we can work with the files
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Download modules
      run: go mod download

    - name: Build
      run: go build -o executable main.go
    
    - name: Chmod
      run: chmod +x executable
    
    - name: List Files
      run: ls && pwd

    - name: Run
      run: ./executable
```

[image]

Comment: The problem seems to be that your executable is looking for a file (or directory) named `$HOME/.totp`, and not finding it.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, thanks for clearing it out